# What are the side effects of habitual cocaine usage, particularly the visually noticeable ones?

Tags: symptoms, lifestyle, recreational-drugs, substance-abuse

If I suspect someone of being a cocaine addict, what should I look for that signals potential cocaine usage?

Comment: http://www.narconon.org/drug-abuse/signs-symptoms-cocaine-use.html

Answer (score 1):

Cocaine is a highly addictive substance. What starts off as seemingly harmless experimentation can quickly develop into a potentially life-threatening addiction with devastating personal, professional, financial, and familial consequences.

Common signs of cocaine use include:

Dilated pupils
Long periods of wakefulness
Loss of appetite
Overconfidence
Over-excitement
Paranoia
Runny nose or frequent sniffles
White powder around nostrils
Legal issues
Missing or being late to work
Financial problems
Mood swings
Irritability
Depression

Common adverse side effects of cocaine use include:

Headaches
High blood pressure
Nausea
Trouble sleeping
Coma
Chills
Confusion
Sweating
Seizures

https://americanaddictioncenters.org/cocaine-treatment/signs